# Symfony Mercure : EventSource don't send cookie

Tags: symfony, http, cookies, mercure

With [Symfony Mercure](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/mercure.html), I want to send a cookie authorization :

- Symfony server : https://127.0.0.1:8000/
- Mercure Hub : http://localhost:3000/.well-known/mercure

I start my Mercure server with this command :

```
mercure/mercure.exe --jwt-key='...jwtToken...' --addr='localhost:3000' --allow-anonymous --cors-allowed-origins='https://127.0.0.1:8000'
```

And this is how I try to send the Cookie `withCredentials: true` :

```
const url = new URL('http://localhost:3000/.well-known/mercure')
url.searchParams.append('topic', 'https://bubble.com/message')

const eventSource = new EventSource(url, { withCredentials: true })
```

In my current page `https://127.0.0.1:8000/message`, in the console, I can see the cookie :

> set-cookie: mercureAuthorization=...cookieValue...; path=/.well-known/mercure; secure; httponly; samesite=lax

**But the cookie is never sent**. In my console, network tab, I can see the eventsource request `http://localhost:3000/.well-known/mercure?topic=https%3A%2F%2Fbubble.com%2Fmessage` but the cookie is never transmitted.

I tried to change `secure=false` and `samesite=none`, but the cookie is never transmitted.

Here is the information from the eventsource request (Mercure Hub) :

[image]

Comment: Cookies set in one domain will not be sent to a different domain. Try accessing both sites via either `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 1):

I recently spend several hours to make it work under Chrome (in Firefox I didn't have any issue for creating & sending cookies):

- React:       127.0.0.1:3000
- Symfony API: 127.0.0.1:8000
- Mercure:     127.0.0.1:5000

Please note that I couldn't make it work using Localhost address (cookie was not being set/send for authentication):

1. Run Mercure and assign origins for Front App (instead of '*'):

```
mercure --jwt-key=aVerySecretKey --addr=127.0.0.1:5000 --allow-anonymous --cors-allowed-origins=http://127.0.0.1:3000
```

2. In React, please setup Rest Api address:

```
REACT_APP_SERVER_ROOT=http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

2. In Symfony setup the config as below:

```
###> MERCURE_JWT_KEY ###
MERCURE_JWT_KEY=aVerySecretKey
###< MERCURE_JWT_KEY ###

###> symfony/mercure-bundle ###
MERCURE_PUBLISH_URL=http://127.0.0.1:5000/.well-known/mercure
MERCURE_JWT_TOKEN=your_secret_jwt_token
###< symfony/mercure-bundle ###
```

4. In Symfony create CookieGenerator and generate the Cookie as below:

```php
    $token = (new Builder())
    ->withClaim(
        'mercure',
         //Using UserId will help to define the targets on publish action
         ['subscribe' => ["http://127.0.0.1/user/{$user->getId()}"]]
    )
    ->getToken(new Sha256(), new Key($this->secret));

    //ATT: As you work in local environment Localhost, path needs to be '' 
    //otherwise Chrome won't setup the cookie. In Firefox this seems not to be a problem
    return Cookie::create('mercureAuthorization', $token, 0, '');
    //THIS WONT WORK: return Cookie::create('mercureAuthorization', $token, 0, '/.well-known/mercue');
```

5. Finally in React put in place an eventSource that will send automatically created Cookie - please remember to add  `{withCredentials: true}`

```js
     // URL is a built-in JavaScript class to manipulate URLs
     const url = new URL('http://127.0.0.1:5000/.well-known/mercure');
     url.searchParams.append('topic', 'http://127.0.0.1/your_topic/{id}') ;

     const eventSource = new EventSource(url, {withCredentials: true});
     eventSource.onmessage = event => {
         console.log(JSON.parse(event.data));
     }
```

Hope that can be useful and save you some time.